# 2008 SQL Server, attach option does not show all the drive letters

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a cluster DB, and i am trying to attach DB files, it doesn't let me navigate to any other drive except for DB? Is there something wrong that i am doing?

Example, if my DB is created in `F:\`, i am allowed to attach only to mdf files from `F:\`

[EDIT/ SOLUTION]
I found the solution on my own, I will need to add another storage to the cluster, if it is a mount point then assign a drive letter, and add dependency on the cluster resource, this would then allow me to attach to the DB as the drive letter is visible in the sql server management studio

Comment: Has either of these responses answered your question. Other can we have more information maybe a screenshot from you cluster administrator.

Comment: Nop, i found the solution on my own, i will need to add another storage to the cluster, if it is a mount point then assign a drive letter, and add dependency on the cluster resource, this would then allow me to attach to the DB as the drive letter is visible in the microsoft sql server studio

Comment: If you could add that as an answer and close the question that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own, I will need to add another storage to the cluster, if it is a mount point then assign a drive letter, and add dependency on the cluster resource, this would then allow me to attach to the DB as the drive letter is visible in the sql server management studio

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Failover Clustering an SQL Server instance is one part of a Resource Group. A Resource Group also contains disks for the SQL Server installation and data files.

You will only be able see and add data files to/for drives that exist as part of the same Resource Group within a SQL Server instance.

If you need to add more disks the cluster administrator can do this for you or see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182326(v=ws.10).aspx.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other drive a local drive on one of the nodes? If so, you can't use that for storing a clustered DB because in the event of a failover the new owner won't be able to bring the database back online.

The storage for your databases needs to be a target visible to all the nodes in the cluster, and also needs to be part of the failover group that holds your SQL instance.

Comment: The local drive is present on the both the nodes

Comment: And is it part of the cluster resource group that holds the SQL instance?